# Automatic sum in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 fields in a table `num1`, `num2`, `num3`.

I need average of these three in another field `avgNum`.

User only insert values of `num1`, `num2`, `num3` using insertion query.

Is it possible to make?

Comment: You mean something like `SELECT (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3 AS avgNum FROM ...`?

Comment: yes. if i change value of num2 automatically average have to change.

Comment: Are you familiar with views (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a trigger, like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `new_table_BEFORE_INSERT`
BEFORE INSERT ON `new_table`
FOR EACH ROW
set NEW.avgnum = (NEW.num1+NEW.num2+NEW.num3)/3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need things to be automated while inserting and updating , you may need to use trigger

- One before insert and calculate the average value.
- One before update and calculate the average value.

Here are the two triggers you can change the table name and field name as needed

```
delimiter //

create trigger cal_average_on_insert before insert on test
for each row
begin
 set new.avgnum = (new.num1+new.num2+new.num3)/3 ;
end;//

delimiter ;


delimiter //

create trigger cal_average_on_uodate before update on test
for each row
begin
 set new.avgnum = (new.num1+new.num2+new.num3)/3 ;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

Here is a test case in mysql cli

```
mysql> create table test (id int, num1 int, num2 int, num3 int, avgnum float(10,2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)


mysql> delimiter //
mysql> 
mysql> create trigger cal_average_on_insert before insert on test
    -> for each row
    -> begin
    ->  set new.avgnum = (new.num1+new.num2+new.num3)/3 ;
    -> end;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> 
mysql> create trigger cal_average_on_uodate before update on test
    -> for each row
    -> begin
    ->  set new.avgnum = (new.num1+new.num2+new.num3)/3 ;
    -> end;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)

mysql> insert into test (id,num1,num2,num3) values (1,10,20,30);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into test (id,num1,num2,num3) values (2,30,40,50);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from test ;
+------+------+------+------+--------+
| id   | num1 | num2 | num3 | avgnum |
+------+------+------+------+--------+
|    1 |   10 |   20 |   30 |  20.00 |
|    2 |   30 |   40 |   50 |  40.00 |
+------+------+------+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update test set num1=30, num2=50 where id=1 ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.11 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test ;
+------+------+------+------+--------+
| id   | num1 | num2 | num3 | avgnum |
+------+------+------+------+--------+
|    1 |   30 |   50 |   30 |  36.67 |
|    2 |   30 |   40 |   50 |  40.00 |
+------+------+------+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Gabor's answer is the correct one - you seem to need that simple math operation, not the SQL functions `SUM` or `AVERAGE`:

```
SELECT (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3 AS avgNum FROM table_name
```

Anyway, I'd recommend you to read about the [3rd normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) in database design and change your table structure accordingly, because think about what happens when you'll have to:

1. store another number - will you add another column `num4`?
2. find all the records that have numbers between 1 and 100, you will have to use a complex `OR` clause, instead of a simple `JOIN`

Comment: i have 20- 30 columns inserting  from different forms. This average value is taking for another equation